# Wordpress The Title Post is not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I've created a condition if 'significado2' custom field is empty, all content is hidding. 
The fields work well on Frontend Wordpress Post, but the title of the post is not showing.

Something went wrong:

```
<?php $post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'significado2', true) ; if (!empty($post)) { ?>
    <div class="conteudo"<?php wpex_schema_markup( 'entry_content' ); ?>><?php the_content(); ?>
          <hr />
<strong><span style="font-size: 21px;">2.  <?php the_title(); ?></span></strong>        
<p><em><span style="font-size: 18px; color: #008000;"> <?php the_field( 'significado2' ); ?></span></em></p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;"><span style="color: #000080; font-size: 14px;"><i><?php the_field( 'ingles2' ); ?></i></span><br>
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 14px;"><i> <?php the_field( 'portugues2' ); ?></i></span></p>

          <?php echo wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $post . 'significado2', true ) );?>
    </div>
```

How can I fix this? `<?php the_title(); ?>` doesn't show on frontend post page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
$post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'significado2', true) ;
```

..because that basically overwrites the global `$post` variable.

So change this line:

```
<?php $post = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'significado2', true) ; if (!empty($post)) { ?>
```

..to this:

```
<?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'significado2', true) ; if (!empty($key)) { ?>
```

And change this line:

```
<?php echo wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $post . 'significado2', true ) );?>
```

..to this:

```
<?php echo wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $key . 'significado2', true ) );?>
```

Or here's the modified code:

```
<?php $key = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'significado2', true) ; if (!empty($key)) { ?>
    <div class="conteudo"<?php wpex_schema_markup( 'entry_content' ); ?>><?php the_content(); ?>
          <hr />
<strong><span style="font-size: 21px;">2.  <?php the_title(); ?></span></strong>        
<p><em><span style="font-size: 18px; color: #008000;"> <?php the_field( 'significado2' ); ?></span></em></p>
<p style="padding-left: 30px;"><span style="color: #000080; font-size: 14px;"><i><?php the_field( 'ingles2' ); ?></i></span><br>
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 14px;"><i> <?php the_field( 'portugues2' ); ?></i></span></p>

          <?php echo wpautop( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), $key . 'significado2', true ) );?>
    </div>
<?php
// You forgot to include the closing } (i.e. bracket). If this causes problems,
// then remove it.
?>
<?php } // end $key ?>
```